# NetBeans jQuery plugin code completion

Tags: netbeans, autocomplete, jquery-plugins

I'm using NetBeans for PHP. When I edit a .js file, it gives me JavaScript code completion. How can I get it to also give me jQuery code completion?

NetBeans 6.9 code auto-complete is not working for jQuery plug-ins.

The code auto-complete is working for jQuery but not for plug-ins such as the validate plugin.

Is this a bug in NetBeans 6.9?

Comment: My 6.8 it works fine. Did not check 6.9 still. Might be any plugin to install?

Comment: Did you use other plug-ins in JQuery? I use the validate plug-in, autocomplete not working and Go To Declaration not working either

Answer (score 9):

Try this

http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/js-toolkits-jquery.html

or

You can also try following

http://forums.netbeans.org/topic15076.html

I add jquery.js to include path of project and it's working fine for me.

Comment: yeah = i dont have any problem with it either

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem. I have Netbeans 7.2.1 under linux (in an Oracle VirtualBox).

- I had copied the jquery library 1.10.2 (not minified) into my own project
- I had added the path into the Project Properties > PHP Include path
- I still had no auto-complete

I found a solution based on [How to include js file in another js file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634644/how-to-include-js-file-in-another-js-file)
I type out the following in the header:

```
var imported = document.createElement('script');
imported.src = 'jquery-1.10.2.js'; // I put the jquery library in the same folder
document.head.appendChild(imported);
```

Now I get auto-completion!

[image]