# How to import/include source files in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, client-side

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to include js file in another js file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634644/how-to-include-js-file-in-another-js-file)

Suppose I have a few JavaScript source files: `a.js`, `a1.js`, and `a2.js`. Functions of `a.js` invoke functions from `a1.js` and `a2.js`.

Now I have to declare *all* these files in my HTML page. I would like to declare only `a.js` in the HTML and "import/include" `a1.js`, and `a2.js` in the `a.js` source file.

Does it make sense? Can I do that in JavaScript?

Comment: To do that you must use a tool like [require.js](http://requirejs.org/), or concatenate your js files (and minify them in the same move, for exemple using the [closure compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/)). You can't specify imports in vanilla javascript.

Comment: @devsundar why didn't you ask for close as duplicate ?

Comment: @dystroy Thanks for suggestion. Initially i was looking for an option to close. I did it now using the "flag" option. It was not intuitive for me...

Comment: @devsundar sorry, I didn't see you didn't yet have the privilege to cast a vote to close.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't specify imports in vanilla javascript.

So your solutions (excluding heavy server side frameworks) are :

- simply do the imports
- concatenate your js files (and minify them in the same move, for exemple using the [closure compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/))
- use a module itool like [require.js](http://requirejs.org/)

As long as you're not experienced, and if your number of files is low (less than 15), I recommend to simply choose the first or second solution. Using a module loader may have side effects you don't want to debug when beginning to learn javascript.

Answer (score 12):

You can import:

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="a1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="a2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="a3.js"></script>
```

if you want to do it directly from the JS, you may use Ajax, this post explains how to:
[include-javascript-file-inside-javascript-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-javascript-file-inside-javascript-file)

Comment: This doesn't help with importing a specific module from a library.

Answer (score 2):

You can bundle JavaScript (and also CSS) files together using certain tools to reduce the number of files you must include.  This also increases page load performance.

These tools combine multiple JavaScript files into a single JavaScript file (optionally minifying the files as well), and multiple CSS files into a single CSS file. This results in fewer HTTP connections from the browser to the server, so there are fewer things to be fetched serially.

ASP.Net MVC 4 has built-in support for this:

http://theshravan.net/bundling-and-minification-support-in-asp-net-mvc-4/

There are a number of solutions for other environments as well such as [Juicer](http://cjohansen.no/en/ruby/juicer_a_css_and_javascript_packaging_tool/).

If you cannot bundle all resources (perhaps some come from a CDN while others are served locally), you can use a load manager such as [require.js](http://requirejs.org).