# How to import another js file into a js file?

Tags: javascript

I have two js files, `a.js` and `b.js`, now I want to create a `common.js` including the other two files. How can I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: At runtime? Build time?

Comment: Are you willing to use PHP to do this?

Comment: Check out this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634644/how-to-include-js-file-in-another-js-file

Comment: @CrescentFresh build time, if i have a common js file so that I needn't import a.js and b.js one by one any more.

Comment: @NobodyElse, the simplest way I've found is by running it through the C preprocessor (cpp) and just using `#include`. [CommonJS](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1) modules are another option; I have a simple build-time implementation in the form of M4 macros if you want it.

Comment: Are you working with JavaScript on the server side or are you actually serving scripts to browsers? Are you just tying to combine the files or are you trying to implement a modular design approach? This question is to vague and should probably be closed.

Answer (score -1):

Check this out : [Require.js](http://requirejs.org)

It's a module-loader on client-side just like Node.js does, makes it easy to import js files or modules.