# Is it possible to create headerfile of javascript and css scripts ?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have no much idea about web programming, I am looking for some way to create header file for javascript and css whether its possible ?

here is scenario, assume I have 100s of javascript and css if I have to create html or php script everytime I have to put these line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/jquery.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/jquery.2.js"></script>
...
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/jquery.100.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../jquery.1.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../jquery.2.css" />
...
...
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../jquery.100.css" />
```

I want to create only one file which contains all javascript and css, and their path and then want to include it in html like this, I expect something kind of C

```
   include 'all_java_css'
   <html>
         <body>
           <p> all included</p>
        </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: use php's include function

Comment: java and javascript is something completely different.

Comment: If you have *hundreds* of separate files, you should be working on a way to combine and compress them server-side.

Comment: Did you mean Javascript?

Comment: somebody give me demo, I want to create 1 file which contains all javascript and css to be included

Comment: You already answered your own question. You basically make a file containing the code from your first block (containing all those `<script>` tags, as well as `<style type="text/css">` tags [do NOT use `<link rel="...">` tags please]. And then inside your PHP file you do a `<html><head><?php include('that_file_file');?></head><body>...</body></hmtl>`

Comment: @Tularis I think he Peter wants to have this done automatically

Comment: Guys I just want to include only file for html, most of the cases js and css I use are common so, I can't search everytime, hope its clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you can try and put as many of them files into one, that would be better. Instead of calling 100 of each, you could only call a few, making run times faster.

Also, add all this scripts to a `.html` or .`php` file for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/jquery.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/jquery.2.js"></script>
```

and save it as `header.html`.

Then in your main file, you can do this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <?php include('header.html'); ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...   
    </body>
</html>
```

You need to make sure that your main file is 1) a `.php` extension and 2) can actually run PHP.

Second of all, you need to make sure `header.html` is in the same directory as `index.php` or whatever the `php` file is.

If not, you can always use

```
<?php include('inc/header/all_java_css.html');?>
```

If you do not have PHP, you can do this:
In the head:

```
<head>
    <meta name="add">
</head>
```

Then using jQuery:

```
$('meta[name="add"').load('all_java_css.html');
```

Comment: Should I include css in same `all_java_css.html` ?

Comment: All css and javascript.

Comment: confused because in above comment tularis told that don't include `link rel="">`

Comment: I'm not web savvy enough to know why that is. Maybe ask him? @Peter

Comment: Thanbks, glad I could help @Peter

Answer (score 3):

Use `include()` php function for this purpose, what you will have to do is.

Make a `php` file and put the scripts file into this file, and include that php file in your file where you need to include js files,

Suppose you made a php file **example.php** with js files.

**example.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/jquery.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/jquery.2.js"></script>
```

**home.php**

```
//with this line you are including all above js files into home.php
inlcude(example.php);
```

Comment: if in case I am not using php then ? only html

Comment: `inlcude(exmaple.php);` is PHP. But in this case you will still have to include your 100 files seperatly just it looks better because it is done in a seperate file.

Comment: It's meant to be `example.php`, not `exmaple.php`. I've fixed it for the confusion (on @JohannesN's reply).

Answer (score 0):

CSS files can be imported from a single CSS file like this:

```css
@import "newstyles1.css";
@import "newstyles2.css";
@import "newstyles3.css";
```

JS is a bit more tricky, but maybe this can help? [How to include js file in another js file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634644/how-to-include-js-file-in-another-js-file1)

Answer (score 0):

You could compile both .js and .css files...

### Javascript - Closure tools

https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/

### CSS - LESS.org

http://lesscss.org/

By compiling both types you could import 2 files do your page.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is better way for you, because if you put more js file in header then make some error, so you will put js file in footer

header.php

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../jquery.1.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../jquery.2.css" />
...
...
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../jquery.100.css" />
</head>
<body>
```

footer.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/jquery.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/jquery.2.js"></script>
...
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/jquery.100.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.php

```
   <?php
    include 'header.php';
    ?>
// do code for content
<?php
    include 'fotter.php';
    ?>
```