# How include a js file in another js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I find this answer to my problem [How to include js file in another js file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634644/how-to-include-js-file-in-another-js-file) but when run my application the resource not be found...
I try to use

```
    var x = document.createElement('script');
    x.src = '../apps/appChangePwd/initApp.js';
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(x);
```

and

```
 $.getScript('../apps/appChangePwd/initApp.js', function()
            {
                alert("okkk!!!");
            });
```

in the first case

```
returns   http://localhost:8080/apps/appChangePwd/initApp.js 404 (Not Found)
```

in the second

```
http://localhost:8080/apps/appChangePwd/initApp.js?_=1404291135662 404 (Not Found)
```

but my js file is in the correct path: `apps/appChangePwd/` !!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-to-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file

Comment: If you manually go to http://localhost:8080/apps/appChangePwd/initApp.js it does not return a 404? Otherwise your path is just not correct.

Comment: is `apps` is your context root ?

Comment: i'm confused. The path `localhost:8080/apps/appChangePwd/initApp.js ` retourn 404... because the correct path is `http://localhost:8080/**ZWebapp2**/apps/appChangePwd/initApp.js`

Comment: $.getScript start at the root (localhost) or at the path were i launch it?
I launch $.getScript in `ZWebapp2/view/App.view.js` and the target file is  `ZWebapp2/apps/appChangePwd/initApp.js`

Comment: ok it work ` $.getScript('apps/appChangePwd/initApp.js', function()
          {
              alert("okkk!!!");
          });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JQuery:

```
$.getScript('My_Js_File.js',function(){
    alert('Javascript File Loaded');
});
```