# How do I reference common strings in JavaScript dictionaries?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, include

I have dictionaries of strings in separate JavaScript files.

```
//a.js
Dict = {
    Something = "foo",
    Else = "bar"
}

//b.js
OtherDict = {
    Fell = "foo",
    End = "d"
}
```

Some of the strings are the same in various dictionaries, and I'd like to define them once and point at them in multiple dictionaries.

```
Dict = {
    Something = Strings.Foo,
    Else = "bar"
}

OtherDict = {
    Fell = Strings.Foo,
    End = "d"
}
```

I tried [using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4634669/1467777), but it didn't seem to successfully include the file. How can I include one js file in another and then reference it in the declaration of a dictionary?

EDIT: The problem was that I made a typo in one of the filepaths. Everything's fine now.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "dictionary" here?

Comment: if the files are been loaded into the same document you don't need to reference the file in the other. It's all part of the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using ECMA-Script 6 and modules, JavaScript code files can't include other ones. You still need to use `<script>` elements.

If you're using ECMA-Script 6, [you can use modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import):

```
import script1 from "js/script1.js";

// Define more stuff here
```