# Call javascript file from other javascript program

Tags: javascript

I want to call Javascript file from my Javascript program without using HTML.
How can i do this without need of html file to integrate my js files ?

Comment: Are you trying to load another script, call a function from a loaded file, bundle your modules into a single file, ...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this script outside of a browser, for example using nodejs, which runs on Chrome's V8 javascript engine: http://nodejs.org/. In nodejs you can create a module and export this module to use in another script. See the following example using nodejs to run:

file1.js:

```
var exports = module.exports = {};   
exports.f1 = function() {
    console.log('This is from file1.js');
};
```

file2.js:

```
var f = require('./file1.js');

function f2() {
  console.log('This is from file2.js');
}

f2();
f.f1();
```

Executing the file2.js using nodejs command the output will be:

```
This is from file2.js
This is from file1.js
```

But if you are using a browser you can see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4634669/2137684