# Using a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, import

I am writing some JavaScript files that will not be used with HTML documents. For example, writing a calculator in one JavaScript file,  where I'll have different `.js` files say one for addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, etc..

I'd like to have each math operation in a self contained `.js` file then have another `.js` file that will #include the other smaller files and can call the functions from them?

Is that possible?

Comment: You can use webpack with `require('otherfile.js');`

Comment: it really seems like js is not suitable for my current project. I had to drop javascript and move to another programming language. I though over the intervening time since that original question js would've modernized a bit. Who wants a monolithic file, especially with js async code execution, name collisions, etc... sure i could wrap up functions and make them anon but wow.....

Comment: yes, use require

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using javascript:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = '/js/script';
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Using jQuery:

```
//you need to change your path
$.getScript('/js/script.js', function()
{
    // script is imported

});
```

Comment: [I call plagiarism!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4634669/2288578)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a synchronous version:

```
function myRequire( url ) {
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open( 'GET', url, false ); // <-- the 'false' makes it synchronous
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        var script = ajax.response || ajax.responseText;
        if (ajax.readyState === 4) {
            switch( ajax.status) {
                case 200:
                    eval.apply( window, [script] );
                    console.log("script loaded: ", url);
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log("ERROR: script not loaded: ", url);
            }
        }
    };
    ajax.send(null);
}
```

Note that to get this working cross-domain, the server will need to set allow-origin header in its response.