# Using Rails, Call JavaScript function in another js file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, function, ruby-on-rails-4, scope

this might be an issue of, I don't even know what to look for, thereby repeating a question. If so please link correct page and I will scurry to the corner in shame! Thanks in advance!

**BEFORE**: I was just running a game with an `index.html` and two `file_name.js` files, and pulling them in the head along with jQuery.

In my old HTML file:(This worked) I had a `game.js` file (doing doc ready, on **click** and **keyup** commands) and a `gamelogic.js` file (managing all the game logic)

My code from my OLD `index.html` file

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery........."></script>
<script src="js/gamelogic.js"></script>
<script src="js/game.js"></script>
```

**Now**:
(Transferring a game over to rails) I'm in a Rails 4 app, scaffolded a game Model.

Created two new .js files with similar names in the `app/assets/javascripts` file

**The problem**: I know both files are being loaded, as I can `console.log("foo")` from both. And I know all my functions work, as when all code is combined to one file, all feature function.

I would like to keep them as two different files as the doc ready section is already kinda long and so is the logic section.

Below is the goal, call a logic function inside of the main game file.

File `game.js`

```
$(document).ready(function() {logicFunction();};
```

File `gamelogic.js`

```
function logicFunction(){console.log("BAR")}
```

**Just a note**: this is not for production or best practices, this is to learn the ins and outs of rails, and what things can and can't do. I doubt my code "should" be split, however I am curious if it's even possible. I will also we converting to coffee once I get functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much detailed explanation on your above question is in the following link. please check through

[How to include js file in another js file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634644/how-to-include-js-file-in-another-js-file)

Comment: Thanks for the response, As this is in a rails file I'm having some issues with the idea that is presented in the link.  (which may be due to my ignorance!) however I know both files are being loaded into the page as I'm seeing the console get logs from both. However I'm not able to call functions from the other, like I was in my very simple app example.

If you have any insight on converting the link to rails app context I'd absolutely love to hear! Thank You either way!


_Edit: Method in link would cause js files to load twice, I think._

Comment: How do you add the js files inside application.js? I meant the sequence. Do you load the gamelogic.js file first and then the game.js?

Comment: Great question and I'm not sure since it's rails it's auto added you do not type it into the head of the layout file. All files in the App/assets/javascript file are loaded, like every rails app.

Comment: Can you please add the sequence inside the application.js for just these two files?
//require gamelogic //require game //require . inside the application.js, just to override the default sequence taken by the rails application.