# Is it possible to reference a JavaScript link in a local JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html, import, include

for example if i wanted to reference this JS link:

`import https://embed.twitch.tv/embed/v1.js;`

I can reference it in an HTML file like this:

`<script src="https://embed.twitch.tv/embed/v1.js"></script>`

But is there a way to reference it in a JavaScript?
I'm trying to use more of it's attributes within my code base, not just within the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference it in HTML, not within the javascript.  Please refer the below link.

[How to include js file in another js file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634644/how-to-include-js-file-in-another-js-file)

Answer (score 0):

Fisrt download the js file you will use , then in your js source file you can use `import ./example.js` to use them, instead od, you use a package tool such as webpack or glup