# How do I link a Javascript file into another Javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, function, import, include

There are two files here in the same folder.
I am trying to invoke a function named greet of `app1` in `app2`.

**app1.html**

```
<script>
  function greet() {
    alert('hello from App1')
  }
  // greet() // commented out code
</script>
```

**app2.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./app1.html"></script>
<script>
  function app2() {
    alert('app2')
  }
  app2()
  greet() // this line of code is not working
</script>
```

Comment: Export scripts to a JS file and import it on both pages

Comment: You cannot use HTML as a src for a JS file. You need app1.js that contains only `function greet() {
                alert('hello from App1')
            }`

Comment: Thank you guys for the help!

Comment: One more question.
Do you know how scripts(line execution) work in HTML code.
So I am requiring app1 and app2 file in my app3.html,
And if I call the method in app3.js (method name is same from both file).
So only the method from file that is written lowest gets called.
Ex:- 
<script type="text/javascript" src="app2.js" > </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app1.js" > </script>
only greet of app1.js will be called coz it is written lowest.

Comment: @YashJaiswal same thing goes with that as well, it won't make much difference you just have to add reference of 2 files in 3rd file(app3.html) and call whichever method you want to trigger.

Comment: Kindly vote the answer if you think worth voting, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call the file in an another `js` file then you have to refer that file in the calling file.

Ex.

Refer the files in the `head` section.

```
  <head>     
    <script src="File2.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="File1.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
  </head>
```

you can have your `body` tag something like this:

```
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   Method2(); // Where you want to call method from another JS.
  </script>
 </body>
```

then, using first file

**File1.js**

```
function Method1(number) {
  alert("Method1");
}
```

**File2.js**

```
function Method2() {
 Method1("Method1 is called in Method2");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend have separate external js files instead of an embedded `<script>` tag, but maybe this can help

[How to include js file in another js file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634644/how-to-include-js-file-in-another-js-file)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.