# How to enable jQuery intellisense on netbeans  7.1?

Tags: jquery, intellisense, netbeans-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NetBeans jQuery plugin code completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135948/netbeans-jquery-plugin-code-completion)

I downloaded the latest Netbeans, placed the following codes but the intellisense is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">           
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a").click(function() {
            alert("Hello world!");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135948/netbeans-jquery-plugin-code-completion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found [this](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/js-toolkits-jquery.html) link and should help you out.

Follow these steps

> - In your project folder, create a folder named js, and add it to your project.
> - Locate the jQuery library that you downloaded onto your computer. Copy the file to this js folder

Further more, it says to trigger the intellisense include the library as such

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
                                         <!-- ^ Be sure to include the version number -->
<script type="text/javascript">
     // Try it inside here and it should work
</script>
```

[image: The display of intellisense]

Comment: Are you sure it is netbeans..I have no javascript libraries in properties

Comment: yeah..i have it jquery works..but no intellisense. I have js/jquery.js under my project

Comment: @BlackFire27, Check the update, thats all i can do right now

Comment: @BlackFire27k, I will vote this question up, may be you will better answers, but this is what generally works for me.

Comment: I got what the problem was..it was the name of the file..jquery-1.7.1.. why yours is 1.4.2 ?!?!.. also all the functions have a line marked over them..why is that?

Comment: @BlackFire27, I just wrote according to the link, no biggie :). I am happy to got your intellisense working.

Comment: This is because you are in an HTML file, but when you edit an external js file, again there's no intellisense.